# Need hellp on Loading Oracle forms from j2ee application

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracleforms

We have two different applications Oracle forms and java web application running on two different servers JBoss and WebLogic respectively.

Currently, users are logging separately and working in two different windows. Now the requirement is to provide a hyperlink/button in each application to switch between them.

For example, if a user logged into java web application with his credentials, in the succeeding page he should get a hyperlink/button as part of the page and by clicking user should get authenticated by oracle forms and load oracle forms page in the same window.

I never worked on such requirement and please help me - whether this is feasible or not?

Comment: Implementing single sign-on is certainly possible.  But implementing it between two unknown applications is way too broad a topic for a forum post.  If you have a design and you're struggling with some specific implementation detail, we can probably help.

Comment: Chandu, Oracle dropped "J2EE" in year [2006](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javanaming-2227065.html) - almost ten years ago. It is ever since called Java EE.

Comment: Hi Justin, I am not sure on the implementation and I need to know, is there any way to communicate with oracle forms from Java application for authenticating a user? (By considering the above scenario)